# Simultaneous confidence bands around an arbitrary function with known point-wise variance

Tags: confidence-interval, multiple-comparisons

Given some estimated function $\hat{y_i} = \hat{f}(\mathbf{X_i})$, with a known pointwise variance $\widehat{var}(\hat{y_i})$, I want to calculate marginal effects $\frac{\partial E[\hat{f}(\mathbf{X_i})]}{\partial{x_p}}$.  I'll do so be evaluating the function across a grid of $x_p$, calculating means and variances for each gridpoint.

Pointwise confidence intervals will be too narrow however, because a statement about the confidence that a particular interval covers the true point is a more narrow statement than saying that a confidence band made of such intervals covers the true line -- there is a multiple comparison problem.

Anything involving a nonparametric bootstrap is computationally prohibitive, and a parametric bootstrap isn't feasible.

Is Working-Hotelling appropriate here?  I see it is typically motivated in the context of linear regression confidence bands.

I'm interested in confidence bands, but also p-values (which should be two sides of the same coin).

My first thought was to do a Wald test across the various values of $x_p$ for which I evaluate the function, but I'm not sure that I can make a statement about the covariance of those values, and anyway that'd be a discrete approximation to a continuous problem.

I'm currently doing a Working-hotelling adjustment to the pointwise s.e., and my measure of "significance" is whether the smallest upper CI is bigger than the smallest lower CI.  This is a hack, and I'm looking for something that is more principled.  Hopefully there is some basic tool or test that I'm forgetting about?

Update:
Following the comments, it seems clear that I need an estimate of the covariance of the expectations of each point $x_p$ for which I take the expectation of the function.  I can get the variance of the expectation at each $x_p$, as $n^{-2}\Sigma_i \widehat{var}(\hat y_i)$.  But how would I get a covariance matrix for a set of $p$ vectors, where each element is a normally distributed random variable with it's own mean and variance?  Simply stacking the means column-wise and taking the covariance would almost certainly be an underestimate.

Comment: It comes down to how the function was estimated, because that determines the covariances among the estimated values. It therefore is difficult to see how you could proceed without explicitly using information about the estimation procedure itself.

Comment: You don't think it can be done with just a set of expectations and variances?  If it were only two, I could treat the difference as normally distributed with a s.e. of $\sqrt{v(x1)+v(x2)}$.  I can't generalize this to $p$ different points?

Comment: Even with two points this won't necessarily work.  The proof of this negative conclusion lies in considering two radically different estimation methods, such as k-nearest neighbor (with a very small value of $k$) compared to (say) linear regression.  In the former the covariances could even be independent whereas in the latter they will be very high.

Comment: Right.  So you're basically saying I'm stuck with a Wald test, and I need to figure out how my gridpoints over which I'm evaluating the function covary, so that I can do the Wald test.

Comment: Wait.  So, the variance of an expectation is the sum of the variances of each point, divided by $n^2$.  What I need is a covariance matrix of these expectations...

Comment: You cannot obtain the covariance matrix *post hoc* (unless you go to even more work than it took to fit the model in the first place): it has to be produced by the fitting procedure.

Comment: Is that a general principle?  Even if I know enough about the fitting procedure to give me a pointwise variance?

Comment: If you understand the fitting procedure very well, you might be able to come up with reasonable estimates of the covariances. For instance, if it is ordinary least squares regression, then there are simple formulas to obtain them.  This is what I have been looking for from the outset: unless you explain exactly what procedure you used, it seems like people could only provide broad, general answers.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid the analytical legwork of going back and deriving a covariance.  The variance has already been derived, in my particular case, as I suggest above.  Thanks anyway.